The server I run on the jar file I purchased through AWS EC2 stops working on its own
I am running a jar file on the server I purchased with the ec2 service. When I run it and close the terminal, a few hours later the jar file I published closes the operation on its own. Also, my nginx configurations stop working, each time I restart the server and redo the nginx configurations. What is the solution to this?
I have no idea about this problem.

Do you have any logs from that jar? How to you run it, what's the configuration? Show the nginx configuration. It doesn't make sense that you have to re-do the nginx configuration when you restart the instance... You need to show us something, so that we can possibly help

I do not have a log of the server being stopped, I only have the spring logs. By Nginx configuration I mean certbot configurations. If I run the jar file again after the server stops working, it does not start with https, domain redirection does not happen, so I start nginx again with the "sudo systemctl restart nginx" command.

You should check spring logs and nginx logs. Those should give some clue as to why it fails
